# Save picture in app-reserved memory in Android 11

Tags: android, image, android-gallery, scoped-storage

Android 11 makes [scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) mandatory. In this scenario, I would like my app to take a picture and save it into some kind of *app-reserved memory* so that the picture is still available when deleted from the gallery. I am using the following approach

```java
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newFile);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
   outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(myActivity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", newFile);
   cameraIntent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
   cameraIntent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
}
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
```

The problem boils down to how do I create `newFile` in the above snippet since `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is no longer usable due to scoped storage.
I have read through the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) and various posts, but the matter appears to be broad and vague. Please avoid posting a bare link to the [`MediaStore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) API.

Comment: What is your definition of "app-reserved memory"? Note that this term is not used presently in [the Android SDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/s/results?q=%22app-reserved%22).

Comment: CommonsWare indeed. I did not mean any term used in the documentation. I mean, any kind of memory that is deleted whenever the app is uninstalled.

Comment: CommonsWare in other words I would like to save my picture in SharedPreferences, if that was possible.

Comment: Use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()` to serve up a location in [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), such as `getFilesDir()` on `Context`. Use that `Uri` in your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request where you have `outputFileUri`.

Comment: CommonsWare thank you, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SAF (Storage Access Framwork) instead.

Create A File using SAF:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "myImage.jpg");

startActivityForResult(intent, your-request-code);
```

Then grab the uri in onActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == your-request-code && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData(); //Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Reference: [Access documents and other files from shared storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files)

Comment: Thank you. Will the file be saved in internal storage by using this approach?

Comment: @Massimo Frittelli This tel the user select a location everywhere he/she wants.

Comment: Hamed thank you, I will have a look at this approach.